# Regex for Lines Under 50 Characters

Tags: regex

I have tried `(^[.*]{1,50}$)/gm` but it simply does not work.

I'd like a line made up of any characters to match this regex.

```
Qwertyuiop
$$%%^^89e7hbequdwanjk
etc should all match, including this line
```

However, lines over 50 characters long should not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying a string of 1-50 occurrences of either `.` or `*`.  If you want a string of any characters, the `[...]` character class is wrong (it enumerates literal characters you want to match); you are looking for `.` without square brackets, which matches any one character.

The regular expression for that is

```
^.{1,50}$
```

Some languages require you to specify a separator such as `/.../` around your regex, but it's hard to tell from your example whether yours is one of them; in this case, you are missing the beginning separator.

The `/g` flag only makes sense if you need to find multiple occurrences on the same line.  The `/m` flag makes sense if the `^` and `$` anchors should match newlines in multi-line text.

If the title of your question is correct, and you want properly *under* 50 characters, change the `50` to `49` (and maybe the `1` to `0`).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex, `[.*]` matches only dots `.` and `*`, since inside `[]` both are treated literally. Try

```
/^.{1,50}$/gm
```

It'll **match** between 1 and 50 of anything. If you also want to **capture** it add back the parenthesis

```
/(^.{1,50}$)/gm
```